# .NET Core AppSetting with Period in Name

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a reasonable way to get a setting in appsettings.json called SomePrefix.MySetting to map to a POCO field in Asp.NET Core? I tried substituting an underscore but that didn't work. Perhaps an attribute I am not aware of...?

Comment: Does `JsonProperty` attribute work?

Comment: I have never used JsonProperty, but if all I have to do is decorate the field and add the json name containing the period, then no, I don't think that works.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I think you need to manually set up your config object then. I can show you code for that if you like, but surely it's just better to remove the periods?

Comment: We are using 1.1.  I am trying to work around a legacy naming convention, but yes removing the periods is an option.

Comment: @DaveZiegler, could you show me a "appsettings.json" sample?
Is it like this?
`{
    SomePrefix: { AppSetting: "etwas" }
}`

Comment: Hard to type this up on mobile, something like {"AppSettings": {"AppSetting.Setting":"valueHere"}}

Comment: So my field would be: public string AppSetting.Setting {get;set;} which is not valid syntax

Comment: A new "ConfigurationKeyNameAttribute" was added in .NET 6 to solve this problem: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36010

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 1.1 version (I'm not sure for older versions), you may use as follow:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace testeCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                        .Build();
            Console.WriteLine( config["prefix.mysettings:etwas"]);

        }
    }
}
```

```
{
  "prefix.mysettings": {
    "etwas": "test"
  }
}
```

You'll need to add the "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration", "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" and "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" references.

Comment: In this example, my setting is AppSetting.etwas

Comment: And prefix.mysettings is just mysettings

Comment: I'm afraid this is not quite what I am asking, but I appreciate the info.

Comment: A new "ConfigurationKeyName" attribute was added in .NET 6: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36010

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you cannot do this out of the box. The main reason is that under the hood the generic dictionary class (`Dictionary<string, string>` if to be more specific) is used to handle all available settings. So when you have config source like

```
{
  "prefix.mysettings": {
    "key1": "value_1"
  },
  "mysetting": {
    "prefix.key2": "value_2"
  }
}
```

it has been converted internally to

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"prefix.mysettings:key1", "value_1"},
            {"mysetting:prefix.key2", "value_2"}
        };
```

and then this dictionary is used for populating POCO objects (if needed).

Therefore, as `Dictionary<string, string>` class is used to store settings, you always can directly access the *Value* from the dictionary by *Key* (this is what @Matheus have said):

```
var value_1 = config["prefix.mysettings:key1"] 
var value_2 = config["mysetting:prefix.key2"]
```

or using helper's methods like `IConfigurationRoot.GetValue<>`:

```
var value = Configuration.GetValue<int>("prefix.mysettings:key1", 80);
```

---

As an option, you may think about the implementation of own custom configuration provider, that will produce another kind of Keys for Dictionary. For example, by replacing `.` with `:` so the result will be something like

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"prefix:mysettings:key1", "value_1"},
            {"mysetting:prefix:key2", "value_2"}
        };
```

so your prefix will become a separate section. But to be honest the same result may be achieved just by modifiing your config file.

Comment: To clarify: I won't have prefix.mysettings, only mysetting and a kvp of prefix.key2:value_2 in your example. I don't need to support both scenarios, option 1 came from @Matheus. Let me digest your answer and get back to you.

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying now. Looks like we need to change the legacy naming convention :)